# What is the relationship between NIST and secp256k1?

Tags: nist, secp256k1

While exploring secp256k1, I came across what seems like the official definition at https://www.secg.org/, specifically in https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf. In terms of authorship, the document only contains references to the Standards for Efficient Cryptography group and Certicom (acquired by Blackberry). However, many resources I come across mention "NIST curves" in the context of secp256k1.

I've searched https://www.nist.gov/publications for definitions of the curve, although wasn't successful. The document's only mention of NIST is as a reference to "National Institute of Standards and Technology. Recommended Elliptic Curves for
Federal Government Use, Jul. 1999", which doesn't seem to be available at NIST anymore, but can be found [here](https://github.com/isislovecruft/library--/blob/master/cryptography%20%26%20mathematics/elliptic%20curve%20cryptography/Recommended%20Elliptic%20Curves%20for%20Federal%20Government%20Use%20(1999)%20-%20NIST.pdf) and seems to contain different curve definitions.

So what's the relationship between NIST and secp256k1? Is NIST the author of secp256k1? What's the relationship between SEC and NIST? Why does the [bitcoinbook say that NIST established secp256k1](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/blob/97df56f77c06813b1e028b5b1f2dbc036f27b1fc/ch04.asciidoc?plain=1#L128)?

> Bitcoin uses a specific elliptic curve and set of mathematical constants, as defined in a standard called +secp256k1+, established by the National Institute of Standards and Technology (NIST)

How does NIST fit into the story of secp256k1?

Comment: Could you quote some other of those «many resources (that) mention "NIST curves" in the context of secp256k1»? The one cited in the question seems isolated. I can't remember secp256k1 quoted as a NIST curve. Is this a confusion with secp256r1, which is in NIST's [FIPS 186-2](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/fips/186/2/archive/2000-01-27) and later?

Comment: Other than the bitcoin book, I unfortunately don't recall the other resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [NIST FIPS 186-4 digital signature standard](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf) (and earlier versions 186-2 and 18-3) recommended several elliptic curves suitable for Federal government use, specifically Appendix D lists curves that also appear in the [SECG SEC 2 document](http://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf), but introducing different designators. Two of these curves predate both documents and coe from the [ANSI X9.6](https://standards.globalspec.com/std/1955141/ANSI%20X9.62)2 document.* To be precise

- `secp192r1` `NIST P-192` (ANSI: `prime192v1`)
- `secp224r1` `NIST P-224`
- `secp256r1` `NIST P-256` (ANSI: `prime 256v1`)
- `secp384r1` `NIST P-384`
- `secp521r1` `NIST P-521`
- `sect163k1` `NIST K-163`
- `sect163r2` `NIST B-163`
- `sect233k1` `NIST K-233`
- `sect233r1` `NIST B-233`
- `sect283k1` `NIST K-283`
- `sect283r1` `NIST B-283`
- `sect409k1` `NIST K-409`
- `sect409r1` `NIST B-409`
- `sect571k1` `NIST K-571`
- `sect571r1` `NIST B-571`

The ANSI X9.62 document specified a procedure for the generation of curve which was followed in generating the curves above.

Other curves from the SEC2 document including the `secp*k1`, `sect163r1`, `sec239k1` curves were not included in FIPS186-5. The SEC group was an industry research group and their document perhaps did not carry the same weight as NIST's endorsement. These curve saw wider adoption into Internet standards such as [RFC 8422](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc8422.html#appendix-A) which try to make the overlap clear. In informal usage the curves often became known as "NIST curves". This loose terminology now seems to have been inaccurately extended to all of the SEC2 curves.

Dave Thompson points out that as of three months ago FIPS 186-4 has been superceded by FIPS 186-5 he writes "the curves are now moved to SP800-186 instead, and there B/K-163 and P-192 are reduced to 'legacy use', all remaining B/K are 'deprecated', the Bernstein 25519 and 448 curves (in Montgomery, Edwards and Weierstrass forms!) are added, and Appendix H 'allows' some brainpool curves and (relevant here) secp256k1 'for blockchain'"

---

(*) - The publication order as far as I can tell is ANSI X9.62 (1999), FIPS 186 (2000), SEC2 (2000) with the curves in Appendix 6 of FIPS 186 dated July 1999 (thanks fgrieu). However these dates are sufficiently close together, that contributions are likely hard to separate out. There was presumably discussion between the different groups.

Comment: Your link is actually to FIPS186-4 which did include those curves (as did -3 and -2 but not earlier) but FIPS186-5, adopted 3 months ago, no longer does; the curves are now moved to SP800-186 instead, and there B/K-163 and P-192 are reduced to 'legacy use', all remaining B/K are 'deprecated', the Bernstein 25519 and 448 curves (in Montgomery, Edwards _and_ Weierstrass forms!) are added, and Appendix H 'allows' some brainpool curves and (relevant here) secp256k1 'for blockchain'.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Many thanks I have added you comment to the main body.

Comment: FWIW: The first version of FIPS 186 with the NIST curves is [FIPS 186-2](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/fips/186/2/archive/2000-01-27), published Jan 2000. They are in [appendix 6](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Publications/fips/186/2/archive/2000-01-27/documents/fips186-2.pdf#page=27), dated July 1999.

Comment: @fgrieu Many thanks, I've edited the footnote.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Hang on. The motivation for using `secp256k1` is because of the reciprocal nature of the "`secq256k1`" curve. Standardising one without the other surely removes that use case.

Comment: Daniel: where do you get that? I don't believe anyone even defined the 'q' curve before Ethereum, more than a decade after 'Satoshi' published Bitcoin, and AFAIK even today no one is using it for anything in/on Bitcoin. His(?) crypto choices seem to have been motivated mostly by what Microsoft CNG provided in Windows Vista.

Comment: You're right, I hadn't realised that interest in secp256k1 pre-dated the ZKP observation. The [Bitcoin wiki]( https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Secp256k1) suggests that it is the "rigidity" of secp256k1 that was behind the choice. The wiki does distinguish the secp256k1 curve from "NIST curves".